# Change Border Color of a Range Without Changing the Linestyle/Weight

Tags: vba, excel

I have a nicely formatted range of cells with different border line weights (some of them are medium thickness and some of them are thin, in no particular pattern). I want to run a macro that changes the color of the borders to grey, but every time I do it, it changes all of the border weights to xlThin automatically. I want to keep the original line thickness so I don't have to go through and change the respective ones back to xlMedium, which would be tedious.

Can someone help me out? Is this possible?

The code I currently have is simple, and it changes the color correctly. It just also changes the line weight automatically, even though I don't specify the weight or linestyle at all: 
`Range("NamedRange").Borders.Color = RGB(150, 150, 150)`

Comment: As a quick workaround, before you change the border color, why not just store the line type in a variable, then after the color change, reset it?

Comment: Seems annoying. @BruceWayne 's idea is good. It could be abstracted into a sub which changes border colors while leaving weights alone.

Comment: @BruceWayne, thanks for the idea, but I don't know how to store it. I tried to store .Borders.Weight as a variant, but it just saves it as "2". Could you expand on how I would do this?

Comment: Can you provide (simplified) VBA code of what you do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This, on my Excel 2016, will only change the color of the cell border, without changing the size:

```
Sub changeColorOnly()
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
Set rng = Range("C6:C9")

For Each cel In rng
    cel.Borders.Color = RGB(150, 150, 150)
Next cel

End Sub
```

Does it still change the size for you?

Edit: Hm, I suspect there's something else going on in your code, as I can recolor a named range without it affecting the borders.  However, just because I was already working on another alternative, you could also use these subs (and tweak as necessary)

```
Dim brdrTop, brdrLeft, brdrRight, brdrBtm, brdrInside

Sub changeColor()
saveBorderSize Range("myNamedRange")
Range("MyNamedRange").Borders.Color = RGB(150, 150, 150)
resetBorderSize Range("myNamedRange")
End Sub

Private Sub saveBorderSize(cel As Range)
brdrTop = cel.Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight
brdrLeft = cel.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight
brdrRight = cel.Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight
brdrBtm = cel.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight
brdrInside = cel.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).Weight
End Sub

Private Sub resetBorderSize(cel As Range)
cel.Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight = brdrTop
cel.Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight = brdrLeft
cel.Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = brdrRight
cel.Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = brdrBtm
cel.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).Weight = brdrInside
End Sub
```

Comment: I think this is the solution; you can replicate the OPs issue by setting the `.Borders.Color` property on a range of >1 cell but if you iterate the cells then the issue does not occur.

Answer (score 0):

Try .Borders.Color = RGB(216,216,216)

I ran the below script to try to identify the closest color to normal gridlines.  My eyes are not great so check it out yourself to find the best color. BTW I agree it makes no sense that MS overrides the border color defying reason.  Angry employees  and too much bureaucracy - that's my theory.

```
Sub borcol()
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 250
        ActiveCell.Borders.Color = RGB(i, i, i)
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the cell border color in a loop, using the enum value for each border makes it easy to loop through them.

This code will change the border color of the selected cell.
If there's no line the `MsgBox` will indicate its value.

```
Sub CellBorderColour()

Dim MyBorder(5 To 12) As String
Dim i As Integer

MyBorder(5) = "xlDiagonalDown"
MyBorder(6) = "xlDiagonalUp"
MyBorder(7) = "xlEdgeLeft"
MyBorder(8) = "xlEdgeTop"
MyBorder(9) = "xlEdgeBottom"
MyBorder(10) = "xlEdgeRight"
MyBorder(11) = "xlInsideVertical"
MyBorder(12) = "xlInsideHorizontal"

For i = 5 To 12
    With Selection.Borders(i)
        If .LineStyle > 0 Then
            .Color = RGB(100, 100, 100)
        Else
            MsgBox ("Borders(" & MyBorder(i) & ").LineStyle is: " & .LineStyle)
        End If
    End With
Next i
End Sub
```